# How to set up uWSGI + Nginx with HTTPS

Tags: django, ssl, nginx, https, uwsgi

I am trying to set up `uWSGI + Nginx with HTTPS`

The prior version worked fine with HTTP, but now it does not work with HTTPS.

The site is using `Django 1.7 and Python 2.7`.

Here are the configuration files.  Can anyone spot what needs to be changed?

**uwsgi.ini**

```
[uwsgi]
# %d is the dir this configuration file is in
socket = my.i.p.addr:9000 
chmod-socket = 666
master = True
processes = 4

# chdir to the folder of this config file, plus app/website
chdir = %dmysite/
module = mysite.wsgi:application

# create a pidfile
pidfile = /tmp/mysite-master.pid 
harakiri = 10 # respawn processes taking more than 20 seconds
max-requests = 5000 # respawn processes after serving 5000 requests

# will be run via `supervisord` so don't need to daemonize
#daemonize = /var/log/uwsgi/mysite.log
```

**mysite.conf** [for Nginx]:

```
upstream uwsgicluster {
    server my.i.p.addr:9000 fail_timeout=0;     
}
server {
        listen       80;
        server_name  mysite.com;
        rewrite ^ https://$http_host$request_uri? permanent;    # force redirect http to https
    }
server {
    listen          443;
    server_name     mysite.com;
    charset         utf-8;

    root            /opt/django/mysite/mysite;
    access_log      /var/log/nginx/access_ssl.log combined;
    error_log       /var/log/nginx/error_ssl.log error;

    client_max_body_size 4G;
    keepalive_timeout 5;

    #SSL Settings
    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/mysite.com.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/mysite.com.key;

    location /static/ {
        autoindex on;
        alias /opt/django/mysite/static/; 
    }

    location / {
        # uWSGI config
        include uwsgi_params;
        proxy_pass http://uwsgicluster;
        uwsgi_read_timeout 300;
        uwsgi_param UWSGI_SCHEME $scheme;

        proxy_redirect     off;
        proxy_set_header   Host $host;
        proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
    }

    error_page 500 502 503 504 /500.html;
    location = /500.html {
        root /opt/django/mysite/templates/error;
    }
}
```

**Additional info:**

The client gives this response: `The webpage is not available: ERR_CONNECTION_RESET`

For the Nginx log, my `/var/log/nginx/error.log` isn't showing any errors.

I don't think that I have the `uwsgi.log` correctly set because I either can't find it, or don't see anything at: `/var/log/uwsgi/...`

Would I check the log for the for the response codes for the page?

Also, does the the `upstream server IP` and the `Nginx IP` need to be different?

If so, will it enter an infinite loop tring to redirect to a HTTPS port when uWSGI is not HTTPS ?

Comment: Can you be a little more specific about what's not working? E.g. How does the client behave, is there a HTTP response code, is the connection terminated by the client or the server, what do the nginx and uwsgi logs say? Throw us a bone ;-)

Comment: @dwightgunning I added as much additional info as I know.  If I need to set the `uwsgi.log` and go from there, maybe that I what I'll try next, but please if you have advice it would be very helpful since I am new to uWSGI and Nginx.  Thank you.

Comment: ERR_CONNECTION_RESET indicates that nginx or the host is resetting the connection. Is the connection reset on the HTTP request (prior to the redirect), or on the HTTPS request (after redirect)? Is nginx actually logging the request in the access log?

Comment: If nginx can't reach the upstream you'll typically get a 502 Bad Gateway so I'd focus on the nginx config first. In fact this can be a good way to isolate the error. If you stop the uwsgi server... then you should 'expect' to see a 502... once you've got a 502 then you can be more certain that nginx is fwding the request.

Comment: Ok, I won't have a chance to try again until tonight or tmr, but thank you. I am going to try your advice.